# Can we use XMPP for instant messaging on web and mobile apps?

Tags: mobile, xmpp, messaging

I want to create an instant messaging web application with ASP.net and a mobile app in titanium. Can we create this App using XMPP (e.g. jabber)?

My requirement is: if a user sends a message from the website, those messages will be shown on mobile, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

of course this is possible.
You can either do this with JS XMPP libraries using BOSH or websockets, or server side .NET libraries in combination with a realtime channel like SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at strophe js http://strophe.im/strophejs/ an XMPP javascript library.

Comment: Hi Sam ,
Can you provide me the link for any tutorial or demo to achieve this functionality ?

Thank you!

Comment: the strophe site linked above has links to tutorials and documentation.